# Too many arguments with && operator in shell?

Tags: shell

```
if [ $(ps -ef | grep date) ] && [ $(ps -ef | grep time) ]
then
     echo "success"
else
    exit 1
fi
```

is giving [: too many arguments error

What is going wrong?

---

From a comment:

> There are two processes running and I want to check if these two processes are running if executing my automated tool. For that I need to check if those two processes are running, you are right when you say `grep` is included in arguments it always succeeds I want to check only if two processes are running leaving out `grep` part. Can I do some thing like checking `$? == 0` but how would I do that for both processes?

Comment: `pidof` is probably better to use. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The `[` command expects rather limited list of values.  The output of your `ps -ef` commands could be generating a lot of data, which won't look like `[ value1 = value2 ]` etc which is what `[` expects.

You could try:

```
if [ "$(ps -ef | grep date)" ] && [ "$(ps -ef | grep time)" ]
then echo "success"
else exit 1
fi
```

This will report success if there is at least one command referencing `date` and at least one command referencing `time` (and since the `grep` commands includes that argument, it should always succeed), but that may not be what you're after.  With a single argument, as enforced by the double quotes, the `[` command checks whether the argument is an empty string or not (success if it is not).

What are you really trying to do?

Comment: There are two processes running and I want to check if these two processes are running if executing my automated tool. For that I need to check if those two processes are running, you are right when you say grep is included in arguments it always succeeds I want to check only if two processes are running leaving out grep part.

Can I do some thing like checking $? == 0 but how would I do that for both processes ?

Comment: If your command names are really `date` and `time`, then you're on a hiding to nothing since they're standard Unix utilities and you'll get false positives all over the place.  If your command names are really `xyz_date` and `xyz_time` or something else distinctive like that, you're in with a better chance.  There are programs, such as `pidof` and `pgrep`, that will search for processes.  Probably you should use one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Better do this, it will be lighter than multiple subshells `$( )` and pipes `|` (many `fork()`s in the background) :

```
if pidof &>/dev/null date && pidof &>/dev/null time; then
     echo "success"
else
    exit 1
fi
```

No need the test commands :

```
[           # POSIX test
```

or

```
[[          # bash enhanced test
```

or

```
test        # word test
```

we use *boolean logic* here.